# Exfat USB-stick: reformat stick or install exfat-fuse and exfat-utils?

Tags: filesystem, exfat

I have just bought a 64GB USB3.1 SanDisk USB-stick but cannot mount it on my Ubuntu 18.10 laptop because the filesystem is exFAT. Having researched exFAT I know now it is a Microsoft file system and it is possible to use exFAT in Linux by installing `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils`.

My question is should I install these packages or simply reformat the USB-stick?

Edit: Question has earned the "Popular Question" badge (over 1,000 views) since it was closed for being opinion-based. Perhaps it should be reopened.

Comment: Ubuntu MATE has both those packages installed by default. So I'd give that a shot before going the reformat route.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to install the packages and everything works just fine.

Comment: Views have nothing to do with whether a question is opinion-based or not. Utter piles of off-topic crap can rake up tons of views.

Answer (score 1):

One can indeed install exfat support under Ubuntu. This is useful if at some time you need to open exfat formatted USB drives on your computer.

However, I do not recommend to install exfat to work with your own USB, which you bought formatted in exfat. The reason I recommend against is that there is no file system *repair* tools on linux for exfat drives. The tool `exfatfsck` that comes with `exfat-utils` checks an exFAT file system for errors. However, it cannot repair corrupted FS: it just reports found errors.

Working systematically with a file system that you cannot repair, is a no-go. Therefore, only keep the current drive in exfat file format *if you also have access to a Windows computer for periodic check and repair*. Otherwise, reformat the drive to **fat32** if you need it to be *widely useable on a variety of systems*, or use the native linux file system **ext4** if it is only to be *used on a linux system*.

Answer (score 0):

FAT32 is supported by any platform. So I would to reformat it to FAT32 to prevent any problems with compatibility in future.

By the way - default menu in Ubuntu disk utility is: ***For use with all systems and devices (FAT)***

Comment: The question relates to exFAT.